# calling pages instead of posts

Tags: posts, pages

In my template, in the functions file, a developer created a code to show the last posts of various blogs (wp mu) on the homepage. I would like to edit the code by showing the pages in place of the posts.

I'll show parts of the code where I think it is necessary to replace somewhere the word post with page.

Can you help me to find out where and how? Thanks!

```
    add_shortcode( 'newswpmu', 'newswpmu_func' );
function newswpmu_func( $atts, $content = null ) { // New function parameter $content is added!
    global $post;

   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
      'title' => 'blog title',
      'blogid' => 1,
      'format' => 3,
      'show' => 3,
      'sortby' => "lastest",
      'exlength' => 100,
      'meta' => "",
      'readmore' => 'disabled',
      'seeall' => 'enabled',
      'seeall_link' => '',
      'seeall_text' => 'see all',
      'classes' => '',
      'format_medium' => 2,
   ), $atts ) );

   $content = wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content, true); // fix unclosed/unwanted paragraph tags in $content
   //print_r($post);
```

(...)

```
// show list articles
wp_reset_query();
switch_to_blog($blogid);

$my_query = new WP_Query('showposts='.$show.'&orderby= ' . $orderby . '&order=' . $order);
$articlecount = 0;
$articlecontent = "";
$get_meta_content = "";
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
    $articlecount ++;

    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full');
    $image_url_small = str_replace(".jpg", "-350x175.jpg", $thumb_url[0]);
    $image_url_big = str_replace(".jpg", "-600x300.jpg", $thumb_url[0]);
```

(...)

```
    $articlecontent .= '

    <article class="post-item  post-' . get_the_ID() . ' post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="' . get_the_date(get_option('date_format')) . '">
            <div class="gp-post-thumbnail featured-content image-above">
                <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">
                    <img src="' . $image_url_small . '" data-rel="' . $image_url_big . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" class="wp-post-image" itemprop="image" height="150" width="300">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="post-item-content image-above">
```

Comment: Let me know if you need something else!

Comment: Hi. Please try and add `&post_type=page` to the end of your `new WP_Query()` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered in the comment by Jack, but what you would do is add &post_type=page at the end of the WP_Query call.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Your revised query call:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('showposts='.$show.'&orderby= ' . $orderby . '&order=' . $order . '&post_type=page');
```